# Why do you say ‘natural resources' in plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Why do you say ‘natural resources' in plural?
We can't count  coal oil nor coal in earth.

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: The context is ‘ Everybody knows that we should make use of limited natural resources as effectively as possible.’

Answer (score 3):

What is being counted in "natural resources" is not pieces of coal or barrels of oil. [Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resource) defines resource as:

> a natural source of wealth or revenue —often used in plural

Coal is one natural resource. Oil is one natural resource. Coal and oil are two natural resources.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could understand that very well.

Answer (score 2):

We don't always say, 'Natural resources' in plural.  There are occasions where the singular, 'Natural resource' is used.

Here is an example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_resource) of both singular and plural used in a single sentence:

"`Natural resource management` is a discipline in the management of `natural resources` such as land, water, soil, plants, and animals"

"A `natural resource` may exist as a separate entity such as fresh water, air, and as well as a living organism"

If we are talking about a singular natural resource such as the ocean, it would be referred to as a natural resource.  If we are referring to hydrocarbons generally, such as coal, oil etc. it would be referred to as natural resources.

Just as a side note, I counted the plurals and singulars in the Wikipedia link:
'Natural resources' is used 40 times.
'Natural resource' is used 21 times.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I could understand very well.